# How to handle a tag change on game that had its name changed with the old one still being prominent?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

[Next Car Game](http://www.nextcargame.com) recently changed its name to "Wreckfest", as the former one only was a working title. However, to accomodate people being used to/only knowing that name, most of the time you're going to see "Next Car Game: Wreckfest" as the title, despite the actual title only being the latter one.

Question is, now, what should that tag look like?

`wreckfest`,`next-car-game` (exists), `next-car-game-wreckfest` are all possible, and while the third one would probably cover all the searches for it, it's not technically correct.

Answer (score 6):

If *Wreckfest* is the official full name, and *Next Car Game* is the working title that people have already asked questions about, then the proper tag should be [wreckfest](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wreckfest). [next-car-game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/next-car-game) should be a synonym of [wreckfest](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wreckfest).

Comment: This has been done, although there was only one question tagged.